# Is it diffacult to setup a trust relationship between windows SBS server 2008 and windows Standard server 2008?

Tags: active-directory, windows-sbs

I am being told by our IT company that setting up trust relationships between SBS 2008 and standard windows 2008 server is difficult. Can any one confirm this?

We have a SBS 2008 server that is doing AD, DNS, DHCP, exchange, file serving, print serving and share point. We are opening another office and want to place a server there to do AD, DNS, DHCP, File server, and Print serving. The offices will be connected via VPN. To me this sounds like a pretty straight forward setup, but this is the first time i have used SBS server.

I would assume you join the new server to the domain and do dcpromo and follow the directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but it's not a trust relationship. Your IT company may be misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish. You don't need a trust as you're not setting up a new domain, you're adding an additional domain controller to the SBS domain, which is perfectly acceptable and straight forward.

Comment: I thought trust relationship sounded wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's nto difficult, merely impossible. you can add an additional DC, however the first DC must hold all of the AD roles.  At this point you should start to consider upgrading to a regular set of servers.

Comment: They do not want to loose some on the features on the SBS like remoting into their work computers. Which i am sure would cost a lot more if it were done with regular Windows server.

Comment: You can set up all of the features that SBS has on "regular" windows servers.  yes SBS has cheaper pricing but has additional limitations.